# In pandas, groupby column1 by row values, and then how to merge column2 and find minimum on other colum3?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a data like this:

```
animal  mergewithcomma  find_min
lion    1,2,3   0
lion    3,4,5   1
lion    1,6,7   -1
tiger   1,2,3   2
```

And would like to have the output as below.

(1) Three rows with lion at column animal is grouped

(2) column mergewithcomma is merged together separated with comma

(3) column find_min is output is the minimum value

```
animal  mergewithcomma  find_min
lion    1,2,3,4,5,6,7   -1
tiger   1,2,3   2
```

I used below python script:

```
import re
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(df, header = False, sep = '\t')

agg_func = {'find_min' : 'min', 'mergewithcomma' : 'sum'}
df_out = df.groupby(['animal'], as_index = False).aggregate(agg_func)

print(df_out)
```

However, my outcome is as below. How can I fix this?

```
animal  mergewithcomma  find_min
lion    1,2,33,4,51,6,7 -1
tiger   1,2,3   2
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
af=lambda x : ','.join(sorted(set((','.join(x)).split(','))))
df.groupby('animal').agg({'mergewithcomma':af,'find_min':'min'})
Out[506]: 
        find_min mergewithcomma
animal                         
lion          -1  1,2,3,4,5,6,7
tiger          2          1,2,3
```

Comment: Thank you so much Wen, this works perfectly. Now I learned how to tie in a lambda to create any random function into the aggregation. Really appreciate it! :)

Comment: In fact I need some more help. I need to sort out the mergewithcomma in order. For example, if [4,5,6] and [3,4,5] were merged together, it gives out [4,5,6,3]. I will need [3,4,5,6] instead. How can this be done?